# opencv dnn module load tensorflow .pb file error

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv

I trained a mnist_fashion model with tensorflow2.4, and then used opencv to call the generated .pb file and the following error occurred.

```
Net net = readNetFromTensorflow(weightFile);
```

String field 'tensorflow.FunctionDef.Node.ret' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
Failed to parse GraphDef file: models/saved_model.pb) in cv::dnn::ReadTFNetParamsFromBinaryFileOrDie

Comment: How did you save the tensorflow model?

Comment: I use googlecolab to generate my model. Use this method: model.save('/model/'), then there are three files under the model folder: saved_model.pb, variable.index, variables.data-00000-of-00001.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, just convert saved_model.pb to frozen_graph.pb.
[https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py][1]